# Limit ftp connections with pf firewall at FreeBSD

Tags: firewall, freebsd, pf

I want to limit simultaneous FTP connections to my FreeBSD server with the pf firewall. For example that only 10 simultaneous connection are possible to the port 20 or 21 from one source IP.

I use for this, this rule:

```
pass in quick proto tcp from any to em0 port {20, 21} keep state (max-src-conn 10)
```

The problem is that every upload or download produce a state entry with the state **FIN_WAIT_2:FIN_WAIT_2** when it is finished. This state will be only removed when the **tcp.finwait** timeout is reached. After 10 of this FIN_WAIT states doesn't accept the server new data connection. This is a problem when you try to down- or upload multiple files sequential with a single ftp login.

Has anyone a good solution for this problem?

Comment: alternately - find an FTP daemon that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

This could easily done with `rctl`. You would run the ftp daemon with a unique UID and limit the number of processes to this UID. That's it.

You may need to recompile the kernel with

```
options RACCT
options RCTL
```

and than you can use rctl like this:

```
rctl -a user:ftp:maxproc:deny=11
```

Have a look at `man rctl` and you will love it ;)

Comment: Oh, and yes. You could also install proftpd - here you can limit this out of the box: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_MaxClients.html